# Colunas Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, media-queries

Estou com uma dúvida no bootstrap (v4-alpha).

Criei uma `<div class='row'></div>` e dentro desta div possuí 4 elementos um do lado do outro.

```
<div class='col-3'>
```

Queria um ponto de quebra que em determinado momento exiba apenas dois elementos um do lado do outro. Mas só consigo fazer a quebra da coluna em que o elemento é exibido sozinho. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode adicionar outros estilos dentro do mesmo elemento para diferentes resoluções de tela. Você pode encontrar na seção [Grid Options](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/) na documentação do Bootstrap. Vou colocar um exemplo para você ter uma ideia.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">Item1</div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">Item2</div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">Item3</div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">Item4</div>
</div>
```

Dessa forma eu defini para :

(col-12) Extra small <576px

(col-sm-6) Small ≥576px

(col-md-6) Medium ≥768px

(col-lg-3) Large ≥992px

(col-xl-3) Extra large ≥1200px

Dessa forma ele vai quebrar a visualização das divs de acordo com a largura da página.

Comment: Perfeito! Desculpe pela demora, deixei esse problema pra depois rsrs e estou voltando agora nele.